# Error: connect EINVAL hubot

Tags: coffeescript, hubot

I'm trying to do a `msg.http`to a localhost url, but I am getting back the following error:

```
Error: connect EINVAL 0.0.xx.xx:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
```

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Edit:
I can of course access the url in the browser.

I've tried (unsuccessfully) to try faking a redirect (using Ubuntu's /etc/hosts file))

Comment: Can you talk about your setup?  Are you using any connectors?

Comment: I'm not using any connectors, it's a pretty basic hubot (experimenting mostly with it at the moment).
I want to do a call to my locally hosted API, and for that I want to use the bot on Slack.
Right now I just do a call to the url, and check if there's and error.
The 'err' variable sends back this error.

Comment: Can you post the URL you are hitting and your package.json  ?

Comment: 'localhost:8000/server/assign',
Like I said in the edit, I can access it in the browser.

Comment: Yea but it doesn't look like its failing trying to hit that. Do you get more info if you export HUBOT_LOG_LEVEL="debug" and then run again.

Comment: It doesn't show anything interesting, it just shows me that it received the command and executes the listener callback for the message.

After this, it sends out the messages I set in msg.send, followed by the error (as seen in the post above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around with the hosts file fixed it!